# Unable to get DropDown list from Array in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I want to display an array of City Names to a Auto Complete text field in ReactJS.

I am able to print the array I needed, however I am unable to get the list in the Dropdown on the browser.

Also I am getting the below error in browser.

I have tried different methods of retrieving the data but not able to.

```
retrieveDataAsynchronously(searchText) {
  let _this = this;

  fetch(`http://webapi.myserver.com/api/v3/locations?name=${searchText}`)
    .then(r => r.json())
    .then(json => {
      var cityNames = json.Data.map(current => current.City);
      _this.setState({
        autocompleteData: cityNames
      });
    });  
}  

const json.Data = [
  {
    "Name": "Dale (e)",
    "City": "Dale (e)",
    "StateAbbreviation": "IN",
    "StateName": "Indiana",
    "StateCode": 26,
    "ZipCode": "47523"
  },
  {
   "Name": "Dallas",
   "City": "Dallas",
   "StateAbbreviation": "TX",
   "StateName": "Texas",
   "StateCode": 68,
   "ZipCode": "75202",
  }
];
```

Expected result is to get those cityNames in the Autocomplete field as dropdown.

Error I am seeing in brwoser.

Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): json.Data.map is not a function

Comment: try do a `console.log(json)` before calling the `.map()`. to see what exact the `json` object was like.

Comment: note: `let _this = this;` is unnecessary, since your callbacks have access to the original `this` because you're using the fat arrow syntax for your callback definition.

Comment: that wasnt the problem

Answer (score 0):

## SyntaxError

You do have a **SyntaxError** on declaring `const json` using `const json.Data` .

```
const json.Data = [
      ^^^^

SyntaxError: Missing initializer in const declaration
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:718:23)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:785:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:641:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:556:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:837:10)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11
```

Try **replacing** with the following:

```
const json = {
    Data: [
        {
            "Name":"Dale (e)",
            "City":"Dale (e)",
            "StateAbbreviation":"IN",
            "StateName":"Indiana",
            "StateCode":26,
            "ZipCode":"47523"
        },
        {
            "Name":"Dallas",
            "City":"Dallas",
            "StateAbbreviation":"TX",
            "StateName":"Texas",
            "StateCode":68,
            "ZipCode":"75202",
        }
    ]
};
```

## Fetch repsonse named json override your json object

The second issue I can see is that `json.Data` will refer to your fetch request return also named `json`, which might not contain a `json.Data` array. You will need to rename your const json, or rename the fetch responsive to avoir name conflict.

```
fetch(`http://webapi.myserver.com/api/v3/locations?name=${searchText}`)
    .then(r => r.json())
    .then(response_json => {
      var cityNames = json.Data.map(current => current.City);
      _this.setState({
        autocompleteData: cityNames
      });
    });
```

Comment: Yea, @sebastienbarbier, I have that corrected. Still get the error.

Comment: Oh probably because your have two variables named json, your json.Data and json returned by fetch ... which might not contain a value for Data. I will update my answer 